# Active vs inactive colors when switching between table views

Tags: navigation, color-perception

I have been working on a web application where users get assigned to specific clients, so by default the can only see theirs.

However occasionally they might need to access other users clients as well. So there is a link to switch between those two views (underlined red in the picture bellow).

[image: All clients currently is the active view]

My opinion:
"All clients" should be gray, that is because its the current table view and you can't click on it. "My clients" are in active blue color - showing that you can click on it.

Clients opinion is reversed - he thinks that the current table view should be blue and other table view options gray.

Please add your thoughts on this!

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Your English is great! No need to apologize :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand why you greyed-out the active page: it should not need to be clickable because you're already on it. However, "greying out" is associated with something being inactive or not applicable.

The problem is that your links serve 2 purposes: navigation, and feedback to the user what they are looking at right now. For this purpose, greying out is not a good choice because you actually want the link to say: I am active! I believe that is why your client wants it the other way around: the blue one looks more active than the one in grey, which fades into the background.

You want to give information to the user about what view they are looking at (My Clients, or All Clients). A few ideas how you can solve this is by using tabs (like the Amazon website) or a switch as in iOS settings: slide the button to the left for one view, to the right for another view.

Answer (score 2):

In a web application I think tabs are the best option for this. Using correct light/dark colour scheme will give users feedback immediately which one is active.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is to use a filter to accomplish this. The list is normally filtered to show only their clients, but in those cases where they want to see all clients, they would turn off the filtering you've kindly provided for them. A filtering control might communicate its use more readily than the affordance issue you've run into with a grayed-out text link.

[image]